# How to display fields from select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done a very long and tedious way of showing details for each option from the select list. I do understand this should not be the way as imagining having to do for hundreds of options. It is simply impractical and a lil daft.

However, at this point in time, I am only testing a logic and have not implemented any data into the database, hence I am not looking at using the 'Select' statement to draw the data out from the database. Hence, I am looking for an alternative java-script for it to read the extra div that will display the details

Code:

select list:

```
<li class="bigfield">
    <select name =".." id=".." onchange = "return val(this.value);">
        <option value ="0" selected = "selected"> .. </option>
        <option value =".."> .. </option>
        <option value =".."> .. </option>
        <option value = "Others"> Others</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Condition that will check which option has been selected:

```
<script>
function val(x) {
    document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = x == "Others" ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("..").style.display = x == ".." ? "block" : "none";
}
</script>
```

This is the long and impractical "extra div block" that displays the each individual different fields when I select  either Agency1 or 2 or 3.

```
<div id = "Agency1" style ="display:none">

      ...
</div>
```

Hence, How am I able to concise these 3 different option field to just 1 such that in my error_log when the value is POST to the controller when I select Agency 1: It will still display the infos that are associated with Agency 1  and if I select Agency 2, display infos that are associated with Agency 2 etc?

Comment: use option value as id of the div. ex: `<option value ="Agency_1"> Agency1</option>` then div id  `<div id = "Agency_1" style ="display:none">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code, Select List,

```
<li class="bigfield">
    <select name ="AgencyDetails" id="AgencyDetails" onchange = "val(this.value);">
        <option value ="0" selected = "selected"> Select Agency..</option>
        <option value ="Agency_1"> Agency1</option>
        <option value ="Agency_2"> Agency2</option>
        <option value ="Agency_3"> Agency3</option>
        <option value = "Others"> Others</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

extra div,

```
<div id = "Agency_1" style ="display:none">
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Name A" type="text" name="agency1Name" id="agency1Name" readonly/></li>
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Registration Num A" type="text" name="agent1RegistrationNum" id="agent1RegistrationNum" readonly/></li>
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Address A" type="text" name="agent1Address" id="agent1Address" readonly/></li>
</div>

<div id = "Agency_2" style ="display:none" >
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Name 2" type="text" name="agency2Name" id="agency2Name" readonly/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Registration Num 2" type="text" name="agent2RegistrationNum" id="agent2RegistrationNum" readonly/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Address 2" type="text" name="agent2Address" id="agent2Address" readonly/></li>
    </div>


<div id = "Agency_3" style ="display:none">
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Name 3" type="text" name="agency3Name" id="agency3Name" readonly/></li>
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Registration Num 3" type="text" name="agent3RegistrationNum" id="agent3RegistrationNum" readonly/></li>
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Address 3" type="text" name="agentAddress" id="agentAddress" readonly/></li>
</div>
```

Jquery function:

```
<script>
function val(x) {
 if(x != "Others" && x != 0){
   $("#"+x).show();
}else{
   $("#extradiv").hide();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Does this mean that if the the user were to choose Agency_2, it will display the respective fields? so the <div id Agency_1> can be used to substitute the other 2 <div> tags?

Comment: yes, for agency 2 `<div id='Agency_2'>` agency 3 `<div id='Agency_3'>`  @Luke

Comment: wait, base on your comment, that means, I still need to input in the additional 2 <div> tags? so in total, i will still have 3 <div> tags one for each Agency?

Comment: It doesn't pop up the extra field at all when I click on the different options

Comment: what are you getting when you click the options @Luke

Comment: If i were to be using your suggestion, I am not getting anything at all.   I am actually looking for 1<div> tag=> "div = agency" to substitute for <div id= Agency_1, Agency_2, Agency_3>, such that when I click on "Agency_3" it will do the check and call "div = agency" to display its values, same for "Agency_1" & "Agency_2", cause I feel that the coding I have done to be very tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.,

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#AgencyDetails').on('change' , function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var id =  val.replace(' ','');
    $('.smallfield').hide();
    $('#'+id).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="bigfield">
    <select name ="AgencyDetails" id="AgencyDetails">
        <option value ="0" selected = "selected"> Select Agency..</option>
        <option value ="Agency 1"> Agency1</option>
        <option value ="Agency 2"> Agency2</option>
        <option value ="Agency 3"> Agency3</option>
        <option value = "Others"> Others</option>
    </select>
</li>
<div class="smallfield" id = "Agency1" style ="display:none">
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Name A" type="text" name="agency1Name" id="agency1Name" readonly/></li>
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Registration Num A" type="text" name="agent1RegistrationNum" id="agent1RegistrationNum" readonly/></li>
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Address A" type="text" name="agent1Address" id="agent1Address" readonly/></li>
</div>
<div class="smallfield" id = "Agency2" style ="display:none" >
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Name 2" type="text" name="agency2Name" id="agency2Name" readonly/></li>
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Registration Num 2" type="text" name="agent2RegistrationNum" id="agent2RegistrationNum" readonly/></li>
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Address 2" type="text" name="agent2Address" id="agent2Address" readonly/></li>
</div>
<div class="smallfield" id = "Agency3" style ="display:none">
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Name 3" type="text" name="agency3Name" id="agency3Name" readonly/></li>
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Registration Num 3" type="text" name="agent3RegistrationNum" id="agent3RegistrationNum" readonly/></li>
    <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Address 3" type="text" name="agentAddress" id="agentAddress" readonly/></li>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery it will be very easy to you

below an example
I've add css style to hide all div and then jquery will show the div according the selected one

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .agency {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<li class="bigfield">
  <select name="AgencyDetails" id="AgencyDetails">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Agency..</option>
    <option value="Agency1">Agency1</option>
    <option value="Agency2">Agency2</option>
    <option value="Agency3">Agency3</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
  </select>
</li>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#AgencyDetails").change(function() {
      var selectedAgency = $("#AgencyDetails").val();


      //hide all divs
      $(".agency,extradiv").hide();

      //get div by id  selected agency e.g.("#Agency1")
      $("#" + selectedAgency).show();

      if (selectedAgency === "Others") {
        $("extradiv").show();
      }
    })
  });
</script>
<div id="Agency1" class="agency">
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input value="Agency Name A" type="text" name="agency1Name" id="agency1Name" readonly/>
  </li>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input value="Agency Registration Num A" type="text" name="agent1RegistrationNum" id="agent1RegistrationNum" readonly/>
  </li>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input value="Agency Address A" type="text" name="agent1Address" id="agent1Address" readonly/>
  </li>
</div>


<div id="Agency2" class="agency">
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input value="Agency Name 2" type="text" name="agency2Name" id="agency2Name" readonly/>
  </li>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input value="Agency Registration Num 2" type="text" name="agent2RegistrationNum" id="agent2RegistrationNum" readonly/>
  </li>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input value="Agency Address 2" type="text" name="agent2Address" id="agent2Address" readonly/>
  </li>
</div>


<div id="Agency3" class="agency">
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input value="Agency Name 3" type="text" name="agency3Name" id="agency3Name" readonly/>
  </li>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input value="Agency Registration Num 3" type="text" name="agent3RegistrationNum" id="agent3RegistrationNum" readonly/>
  </li>
  <li class="bigfield">
    <input value="Agency Address 3" type="text" name="agentAddress" id="agentAddress" readonly/>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to further ask that `.agency {
  display: none;
}` is to be put within <script></script> as well together with `$(function()`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted.

JQuery

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#AgencyDetails').change(function(){

        var id = $(this).val().replace(/\s+/, "");
        console.log(id);

        $("#extradiv").children('div').each(function(){

            if ( $(this).attr("id") == id ) {

                $(this).show();

            } else if ( id == "0" ) {

                $(this).hide();

            } else if ( id == "Others" ) {

                $(this).show();

            } else {

                $(this).hide();

            } 

        })

    });

});

</script>
```

HTML

```
<li class="bigfield">
    <select name ="AgencyDetails" id="AgencyDetails">
        <option value ="0" selected = "selected"> Select Agency..</option>
        <option value ="Agency 1"> Agency1</option>
        <option value ="Agency 2"> Agency2</option>
        <option value ="Agency 3"> Agency3</option>
        <option value = "Others"> Others</option>
    </select>
</li>

<div id ="extradiv">

    <div id = "Agency1" style ="display:none">
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Name A" type="text" name="agency1Name" id="agency1Name" readonly/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Registration Num A" type="text" name="agent1RegistrationNum" id="agent1RegistrationNum" readonly/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Address A" type="text" name="agent1Address" id="agent1Address" readonly/></li>
    </div>


    <div id = "Agency2" style ="display:none" >
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Name 2" type="text" name="agency2Name" id="agency2Name" readonly/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Registration Num 2" type="text" name="agent2RegistrationNum" id="agent2RegistrationNum" readonly/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Address 2" type="text" name="agent2Address" id="agent2Address" readonly/></li>
    </div>


    <div id = "Agency3" style ="display:none">
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Name 3" type="text" name="agency3Name" id="agency3Name" readonly/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Registration Num 3" type="text" name="agent3RegistrationNum" id="agent3RegistrationNum" readonly/></li>
        <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Address 3" type="text" name="agentAddress" id="agentAddress" readonly/></li>
    </div>

</div>
```